# URLParams of reactivesearch with next-routes

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, reactivesearch

Does anyone have an idea on how to handle the url writing of URLParams of some reactivesearch component with `next-routes`?

My pattern for, let's say some country filter, should look like this: `pattern: '/country/:countryname/` instead of `?country="{countryname}"`

That's how I implement it:

```
<SingleDropdownList
    componentId="country"
    dataField="locationInformation.country.name"
    URLParams
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default the `URLParams` will set the value of the components based on the query params (by looking for a matching `componentId` in the url). However, when using a custom url the default `URLParams` won't work because it can't figure out which value to pass to the component.

In such cases you may use the `defaultSelected` prop to initialize the component's value reading it from the URL. In case of `next-routes`, you could pick the `slug` from the `query` and pass the required value to the `SingleDropdownList` component:

```
render() {
  const defaultValue = this.props.url.query.slug; // or parse it to find the required value
  return (
    ...
      <SingleDropdownList
        ...
        defaultSelected={defaultValue}. // value from url
      />
    ...
  );
}
```

You can also update the url when a value is selected using the `onValueChange` prop [docs](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/list-components/singledropdownlist.html#extending):

```
<SingleDropdownList
  ...
  onValueChange={(value) => Router.push('country', { slug: value })}
/>
```